# bad_alloc from referencing pointers C++

Tags: c++, pointers

Current writing a program to solve a NxM sliding puzzle using BFS. Keep getting bad_alloc with this code

```
  while(tempNode.getPNode()!=NULL)
            {
              cout<<"Direction is: "<< tempNode.GetDirection()<<endl;
              tempNode = tempNode.GiveParentNode();
            }
```

getPNode returns a Node pointer that is either pointed to the parent node or NULL if it was the root node. This code would loop 2 or 3 times (tried with different puzzle) and then throws a bad_alloc for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

[`std::bad_alloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/bad_alloc/) - type of the exceptions thrown by the standard definitions of operator new and operator new[] when they fail to allocate the requested storage space

Since you show no memory handling code here, its not possible to tell what went wrong.